# What's the significance of the Blue Hallway before the 'two door' room?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

Is there any significance to the Blue Hallway that appears sometimes before the 'two doors' room at the start?  And has anyone else seen this hallway and found out that significance?

Comment: You are not talking about the one directly after the start right ?

Comment: That's right. I'm talking about the long blue hallway that appears after the second set of cubicles and before the "two doors" room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This blue hallway (which is not directly at the start) is another random element of the game. It doesnt bring much except randomness in the game. Kind of like when you begin the game again and have a straight corridor to the 2 doors room.

Comment: Or the beginning offices have papers all over the floor.

Comment: @Batophobia i coulndn't mention all the random event but yes, you could even mention the phone call, the other employe etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've read somewhere that this hallway was kind of a mandatory shortcut to unlock the *Speed Run* achievement.

> **Speed run**
>
> Complete The Stanley Parable in under 4 minutes 22 seconds (not including load times)

Source : http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186748414#160740

Comment: That's actually the Blue Room, which appears right as you exit your office.  This blue hallway appears after the second set of cubicles in an otherwise normal set of hallways.