# The game started differently. Am I getting somewhere?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

After playing out one of the paths in the Stanley Parable, I noticed that the next time I started the game the exit from my office led almost directly to the first choice with the two doors.

Is this something that happens at random, or am I on to some sort of grander multi-playthrough path?

Comment: Did this happen after you found the big room with the monitors?

Comment: @Studoku No, it did not. It was after the path where you choose "wrong" twice, and then stay on the cargo lift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a random element of the game.  See also:

- [This list](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=201405381) of all the random starting elements.
- [What's the significance of the Blue Hallway before the 'two door' room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136327)

Answer (score -2):

Every time you restart the game it will randomly be a new start.